# find the max product of 2 array element

Tags: c++

i tried to find the max product of 2 array element so my idea is to sort the array and multiply the last 2 elements. my code is working with different test cases but in test case . 
2 
100000 90000 
it has wrong answer only in this test case ! 
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int n;
cin >> n ;
int arr [n];


for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    cin>> arr[i] ;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
        if (arr[j]<arr[i])
            swap(arr[j],arr[i]) ;


cout <<arr[n-1]<<"  "<<arr[n-2] <<endl;
int res = arr[n-1] * arr[n-2];
cout << res ;





}
```

Comment: You cannot use the following:                                                                                               int  n;                                                                                                                                                                                                                          and then use cin >> n to initialize your array because the array size needs to be known at compile time NOT at runtime!

Comment: `j<=n` will throw out of index error.

Comment: the code works correctly in all test cases except 90000  100000

Comment: @MosheRabaev that is not correct. Some compilers will allow for variable langth arrays. They are called `VLAs or Variable Length Arrays`

Comment: It needs to be noted that VLAs are non-standard for a number of good reasons. My big two are they break `sizeof`, and depending on the implementation they can overflow static memory very, very quickly. From a student's Point of View, what if the marker uses a compiler that does not support VLA? One of the easiest zeroes they ever handed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num = 0, size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> numbers(size);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) {
        std::cin >> num;
        numbers[counter] = num;
    }

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    int max = numbers[size - 1] * numbers[size - 2];
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Since you are utilizing *Variable Length Arrays*, why not just use a vector?

The code above gets numbers from `std::cin`, and puts them into the vector. The vector is then sorted. We have a variable for the size of `vector - 1`, so we don't go out of bounds accessing our elements. `max` is the initialized to the product of the last two elements of the vector. Finally, the product gets printed.

Comment: worng answer still !

Comment: @AliAbdelSamie can you explain how this doesn't work?

Comment: 3 1 2 3 the answer will be 9 but the correct answer is 6

Comment: @AliAbdelSamie no, the answer would be 9 since the product of `3` and `3` = `9` Since `3` is the biggest number, and it appears twice, they are the highest operands for the product.

Comment: no my friend the first 3 is the number of array elements

Comment: @AliAbdelSamie then in that case, when I plug it into my program... I get `6`. http://prntscr.com/c1r41x

Comment: +1 and another note: you had a good thing going with the test of  `std::cin >> num`. EOF can be hard to force on stdin, but the test also caught  entry of non-integers. Still worth doing the test even if only to print messages mocking the user's typing accuracy.